# Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'xxx.xx.xxx.x' to the list of known hosts

Tags: git, github

I forked someone's repo and then got the warning in my terminal. I'm not getting the warning when I clone into forked repos from that user.

I looked into the list here: https://api.github.com/meta but couldn't find the IP address on there. Are there other places where I can verify whose IP address this is, and whether I should be concerned? Thank you!

```sh
git clone git@github.com:gminova/mc-client-side-validation.git
Cloning into 'mc-client-side-validation'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.113.4' to the list of known hosts.
remote: Enumerating objects: 6, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 93 (delta 0), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 87
Receiving objects: 100% (93/93), 20.94 KiB | 191.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (28/28), done.
```

Comment: That is an IP address for GitHub, not that user. You are cloning the code from GitHub's servers. That warning will come up every time the ssh process connects to a new server. If you want to verify that the IP really belongs to GitHub, you could use a tool like this: https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/140.82.113.4
Also, welcome to StackOverflow. I'm not an expert, but this question *may* have been more appropriate on Server Fault (a sister site to SO)

Comment: Thank you for the link and feedback! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.113.4' to the list of known hosts.

It is in the meta list:

```
"git": [
    "192.30.252.0/22",
    "185.199.108.0/22",
    "140.82.112.0/20",
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

A /20 subnet mask covers the range 140.82.112.1 - 140.82.127.254, and so does include 140.82.113.4.

Comment: That's great to know where to look for those IP addresses and that the IP address of the warning is in the range of the list. But every time I pull or fetch from my github repo, I get that warning. Is there a way to stop it? I tried doing what they say on [this page](https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/) but it didn't work. I still get the warning. Don't know what to do.....